# Android RecyclerView Firebase Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview, android-fragment

Buenas Tardes,Estoy desarrollando una app con tabs y fragments,El problema que tengo es que al iniciar la app el recyclerView que esta dentro de una fragment no me muestra nada al principio,pero si me muevo hacia el ultimo tabs y vuelvo al tab que tiene el recyclerView recien ahi es como que reacciona ,Les envio el codigo para ver si me pueden ayudar

Este es el que carga los tabs y los fragments

```
 package com.example.juego.frasear.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.juego.frasear.R;
import com.example.juego.frasear.adapters.adapterPrincipal;
import com.example.juego.frasear.fragments.homeFragment;
import com.example.juego.frasear.fragments.jugadoresFragment;
import com.example.juego.frasear.fragments.perfilFragment;
import com.example.juego.frasear.fragments.rankingFragment;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

/**
 * Created by franco on 26/08/16.
 */
public class principal extends AppCompatActivity {






    private Toolbar toolbar,toolbarJugadores,toolbarMiPerfil;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private TextView toolbar_title,toolbarJug_title,
            toolbarMiPerfil_title;
    //  that will host the section contents.
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Typeface font_roboto_light,font_bigboss,font_frase_menu,font_gametime;
    String email_usuario;
    //controlador c=new controlador();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        font_gametime = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Game_Time.ttf");
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //toolbar.setTitle("Frasear");
        toolbar_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        toolbar_title.setTypeface(font_gametime);
        toolbar.hideOverflowMenu();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user==null)
        {
            irAlogin();
        }
        if(user!=null) {

           // Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
          //  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the activity.
            // sectionsPagerAdapter that is used as the adapter for a ViewPager.

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
     //      viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerChangeListener());

            setupViewPager(viewPager);


            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            // tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            setupTabIcons();

        }
    }  // fin oncreate

    private void irAlogin()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, login.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icono_home, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icono_jugadores, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icono_ranking, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

        TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

        tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icono_perfil, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapterPrincipal adapter = new adapterPrincipal(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //ViewPagerAdapter adapter =new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new homeFragment(),"HOME" );
        adapter.addFragment(new jugadoresFragment(), "PLAYERS");
        adapter.addFragment(new rankingFragment(), "RANKING");
        adapter.addFragment(new perfilFragment(), "PERFIL");
        // mostrarToolbarsHome();
        //adapter.esconderToolbars();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




   /* public ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagerChangeListener() {
        return new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                if(tabLayout.getTabAt(1).isSelected()) {
                    jugadoresFragment j =new jugadoresFragment();

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

               if(tabLayout.getTabAt(1).isSelected()) {

                   jugadoresFragment j =new jugadoresFragment();


               }

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        };

    }*/


  /*  public void mostrarToolbarsHome() {
       toolbarJugadores.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbarMiPerfil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void mostrarToolbarsJugadores()
    {
        toolbarJugadores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbarMiPerfil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    public void mostrarToolbarMiPerfil()
    {
        toolbarMiPerfil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbarJugadores.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


*/
}
```

Luego tenemos el fragment del recyclerView

```
package com.example.juego.frasear.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.juego.frasear.R;
import com.example.juego.frasear.adapters.recyclerAdapter;
import com.example.juego.frasear.models.controlador;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by franco on 27/08/16.
 */
public class jugadoresFragment extends Fragment {

    FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   //ArrayAdapter<String> adaptadorListaAmigos;
     controlador c;
    //principal p;
   // DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ArrayList<String> listaNombres;
    ArrayList<String> listaUrl;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //DataSnapshot data;
    //private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;



    public jugadoresFragment() {
        c=new controlador();
        // Required empty public constructor
        //c.getNombreAsyncronicos();




}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listaNombres=c.getAmigosNombres(user.getEmail());
        listaUrl=c.getAmigosUrl(user.getEmail());
        String hola="hola";
    //leadsNames=c.getAmigos();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jugadores, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

            //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            LinearLayoutManager llmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
            llmanager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llmanager);


            recyclerAdapter myAdapter = new recyclerAdapter(v.getContext(),listaNombres,listaUrl);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        return v;
    }


    }
```

Luego la clase del recyclerView

```
package com.example.juego.frasear.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.juego.frasear.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import jp.wasabeef.glide.transformations.CropCircleTransformation;

/**
 * Created by franco on 12/09/16.
 */
public class recyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> imagenes;

    public recyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items,ArrayList<String> imagenes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items= items;
        this.imagenes=imagenes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder itemsViewHolder, int i) {
        itemsViewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(i));;
        Glide.with(this.context).load(imagenes.get(i))
                .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(context))
                .into(itemsViewHolder.vImagen);

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Campos de la lista
        public TextView vTitle;
       public ImageView vImagen;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            vImagen= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagenAmigos);
        }
    }

}
```

Luego tengo la clase controlador

```
public ArrayList<String> getAmigosNombres(String email)
    {
        catalogo_amigos cat=new catalogo_amigos();
        ArrayList<String> rtas=cat.getAmigosNombres(email);
        //String hola="asdsa";
        return rtas;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAmigosUrl(String email)
    {
        catalogo_amigos cat=new catalogo_amigos();
        ArrayList<String> rtas=cat.getAmigosUrl(email);
        return rtas;
    }

    public void guardarAmigos(ArrayList<amigo> listaAmigos,String email)
    {
        catalogo_amigos cat=new catalogo_amigos();
        cat.guardarAmigos(listaAmigos,email);
    }

    public void getNombreAsyncronicos()
    {
        catalogo_asynco a=new catalogo_asynco();
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> array=a.execute("fml_z@hotmail.com");
        try {
            ArrayList<String> as= array.get();
            String hola="hola";
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

luego tengo la clase catalogo_amigos que es donde hace la interaccion con firebase

```
package com.example.juego.frasear.databases;

import android.os.Handler;

import com.example.juego.frasear.models.amigo;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Created by franco on 16/09/16.
 */
public class catalogo_amigos  {

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ArrayList<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listaUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    Long nro;
    Handler mhandler,mhandler1;


    public catalogo_amigos()
    {
            mhandler=new Handler();
            mhandler1=new Handler();

    }


    public void guardarAmigos(ArrayList<amigo> lista, String email) {
        ArrayList<String> lista_name = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> lista_url = new ArrayList<>();
        String delimitadores = "@";
        String[] emailCortado = email.split(delimitadores);
       /*for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
        {
            amigo a=lista.get(i);
            lista_name.add(i,a.getName());
        }
        //String nro=String.valueOf(i);
        DatabaseReference amig = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);;
        amig.setValue(lista_name);
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
        {
            amigo a=lista.get(i);
            lista_url.add(i,a.getUrl());
        }
        DatabaseReference url = ref.child("imagenes_amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
        url.setValue(lista_url);
*/
        DatabaseReference am = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
        am.setValue(lista);

    }


    public ArrayList<String> getAmigosNombres(final String email) {


                //Aquí ejecutamos nuestras tareas costosas


        String delimitadores = "@";
        String[] emailCortado = email.split(delimitadores);
        DatabaseReference amigos = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
        amigos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> i = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> radiatosIterator = i.iterator();
                while (radiatosIterator.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot c = radiatosIterator.next().child("name");
                    String name = c.getValue(String.class);
                    listaNombres.add(name);

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

        return listaNombres;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAmigosUrl(final String email) {


        mhandler1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String delimitadores = "@";
                String[] emailCortado = email.split(delimitadores);
                DatabaseReference amigos = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
                amigos.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Iterable<DataSnapshot> i = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                        Iterator<DataSnapshot> radiatosIterator = i.iterator();
                        while (radiatosIterator.hasNext()) {
                            DataSnapshot c = radiatosIterator.next().child("url");
                            String url = c.getValue(String.class);
                            listaUrl.add(url);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            });

        return listaUrl;
    }

}
```

Estoy dudando tambien que se cargen mal los tabs ,este seria el adapter donde se cargan los tabs

```
package com.example.juego.frasear.adapters;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class adapterPrincipal extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    public adapterPrincipal(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);

    }

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();




    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {

        return mFragmentList.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment,String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }


}
```

Desde ya muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias probar esta solucion en tu metodo *setupViewPager*

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NumeroDeTabsQueTengas);
```

**Establezca el número de páginas que deben conservarse en cualquier lado de la página actual en la jerarquía de vistas en un estado inactivo. Las páginas más allá de este límite se crearán desde el adaptador cuando sea necesario.**

el minimo valor es 1

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que `getAmigosNombres` y `getAmigoUrls` son asincrónicos. Al cargar el adapter la primera vez, el `notifyDataSetChanged` es llamado antes de que llegue la respuesta de Firebase. Y cuando finalmente llega la respuesta, el adapter no es refrescado (solamente se agregan los items a la lista).
Por eso es que luego de navegar entre los tabs aparecen los resultados, dado que el RecyclerView vuelve a renderizar su contenido.

La manera directa de resolverlo es llamar a `notifyDataSetChanged` luego de actualizar el contenido.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Iterable<DataSnapshot> i = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
    Iterator<DataSnapshot> radiatosIterator = i.iterator();
    while (radiatosIterator.hasNext()) {
        DataSnapshot c = radiatosIterator.next().child("url");
        String url = c.getValue(String.class);
        listaUrl.add(url);
    }

    // Luego de actualizar el listado se debe notificar al adapter
}
```

Como seguramente no quiera hacer `notifyDataSetChanged` dentro del controller, puede preferir en este contexto pasarle un callback a `getAmigosNombres` (el cual recibiría el resultado de la llamada a firebase), y llamar al notify dentro de ese callback. Pero esa ya es una cuestión de diseño que quedará a su criterio.

Answer (score -1):

Me pasó lo mismo, pero lo solucioné en esta línea que tiene:

```
LinearLayoutManager llmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
```

Lo cambie por

```
LinearLayoutManager llmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

`getActivity()` obtiene el contexto de la activity ya que el fragmento no tiene su propio contexto.

Comment: Hola Guillermo, creo que esta respuesta puede ser correcta (no estoy seguro porque no sé mucho de Java o Android :P)... la he editado para que el formato se ajuste mejor al del sitio, te recomendaría que leyeses [ask] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) en el centro de ayuda, para que tus respuestas sean mejor recibidas.